# MoQ how to set up for multiple calls of the same method

Tags: vb.net, moq

I have problem setting up the mock to fail if the user has attempted to log in three time with failure. My code looks like this:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub User_LogIn_With_Three_Failed_Attempts_AccountLocks_Pass()
    ' arrange
    Dim logInMock As New Moq.Mock(Of IUserLoginRepository)()
    logInMock.Setup(Function(repo) repo.LogInUser(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String))).Returns(False)
    ' Todo: have to instruct the mock that if it is repeated 3 times then lock the account. How to do this????

    ' act
    Dim logInBO As New LogInBO(logInMock.Object)
    logInBO.LogIn("someusername", "someWrongPassword")
    logInBO.LogIn("someusername", "someWrongPassword")
    logInBO.LogIn("someusername", "someWrongPassword")

    ' verify
    logInMock.Verify(Function(r) r.LogInUser("someusername", "someWrongPassword"), times:=Times.Exactly(3))
    logInMock.Verify(Function(r) r.IsAccountLocked = True)
End Sub
```

Assuming my repository looks something like:

```
public interface IUserLoginRepository
{
    bool LogInUser(string userName, string password);
    bool IsAccountLocked { get; }
    bool ResetPassword(string userName, string password);
    int FailedAttempts(string userName);
    bool LockAccount(string userName);
}
```

appreciate any tips and would love the moq syntax in VB.Net ;-)

The LoginBo code is like:

```
public bool LogIn(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (_logInRepo.IsAccountLocked)
            // TODO log error
            return false;

        if (_logInRepo.LogInUser(userName, password))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_logInRepo.FailedAttempts(userName) == 3) // this should increment the failed attempts and return the value
                _logInRepo.LockAccount(userName);
        }

        // Log error
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now i got what you want to do exactly. so ignore what i wrote before the edit.

```
Dim logInMock As New Moq.Mock(Of IUserLoginRepository)()

Dim IsAccountLocked = false

logInMock.SetupGet(Function(repo) repo.IsAccountLocked).Returns(Function() { return isAccountLocked })


dim amountOfFailedlogIns = 0;
logInMock.Setup(Function(repo) repo.LogInUser(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String))).Callback(Function(repo) amountOfFailedlogIns++).Returns(False)

logInMock.Setup(Function(repo) repo.FailedAttempts(It.IsAny(Of String))).Returns(Function(repo) return amountOfFailedlogIns)
```

In C#:

```
Mock<IUserLogicRepository> logInMock = new Mock<IUserLoginRepository>();

bool IsAccountLocked = false

logInMock.SetupGet(repo => repo.IsAccountLocked).Returns(() => { return isAccountLocked; })


int amountOfFailedlogIns = 0;
logInMock.Setup(repo => repo.LogInUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))).Callback(repo => { amountOfFailedlogIns++; }).Returns(false);

logInMock.Setup(repo => repo.FailedAttempts(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(repo => { return amountOfFailedlogIns; })
```

Comment: Hi eyossi, thanks for the post. this does not seem right though. logInBo.Setup?? loginBo is my class under test and I do not want to mock it. What I want is if the user attempts 3 times to log in and fails then the Repository LockAccount is called. I should be able to verify that LockAccount is called and AccountIsLocked is true. Can you please update your code so clarify the things? I simply wanted some code to fill the 'TODO' thingo in my above test function.

Comment: Who calls the `LockAccount` method? logInBO? and who changes the `IsAccountLocked` value? (i guess that here it is the object that implements IUserLoginRepository itself)

Comment: well yea it is LogInBo which is getting the LogInRepository as construction dependency that I am trying to mock. ... The code in in LoginBo looks like:

Comment: public bool LogIn(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (_logInRepo.IsAccountLocked)
                // TODO log error
                return false;

            if (_logInRepo.LogInUser(userName, password))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_logInRepo.FailedAttempts(userName) == 3) // this should increment the failed attempts and return the value
                    _logInRepo.LockAccount(userName);
            }

            // Log error
            return false;
        } '

Comment: your code does not compile at all ... maybe put your code in c# or whatever that works for you...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `LoginRepo` is what you want to mock. You set up your mock repo so that it returns a user who has already failed to log in twice, then call LoginBo with bad credentials, then verify that the account has been locked in the Mock repository.

To clarify, to test the situation of failing to log in 3 times, you don't call LoginBo 3 times; you call it once with a setup that is already primed for failure.